# Quick sort algorithm not working! cannot figure out why.

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, quicksort

I used the wikipedia algorithm, it's simply not working and I can't see what I did wrong, any help would be appreciated! I'm confused because i thought the lo value should be 0, but then later it says to do lo -1?

```
  int partition(vector<int>v, int lo, int hi)
   {
    int pivot = v[lo];  //wikipedia says to use the low value
    int i = lo - 1;
    int j = hi + 1;
    for (;;)
    {
     do
        i = i + 1;
    while (v[i] < pivot);

        do
            j = j - 1;
        while (v[j] > pivot);

        if (i <= j)
            return j;

            swap(i, j);

 }

}

void quickSort(vector<int>v, int lo, int hi)
{
    if (lo < hi)
    {
    int p = partition(v, lo, hi);
    quickSort(v, lo, p);
    quickSort(v, p + 1, hi);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Does not work](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/) is not a good problem description.

Comment: You are passing your vectors by value.

Comment: To clarify drescherjm's comment, the two affected lines should be   int partition(vector<int> `&`v, int lo, int hi) and void quickSort(vector<int> `&`v, int lo, int hi) . Since this is C++, you could change the do whiles to while(v[++i] < pivot); and while(v[--j] > pivot);  (don't forget the trailing ;).